# How to write following code without multiple if-else-statements using C++?

Tags: c++

Below are the conditions. How to write an equivalent code without using multiple if statements?

```
if ((direction >= 0 && direction <= 11.25) || (direction > 348.75 && direction <= 360)) {
    Dir = "N";
    } else if (direction > 11.25 && direction <= 33.75) {
    Dir = "NNE";
    } else if (direction > 33.75 && direction <= 56.25) {
    Dir = "NE";
    } else if (direction > 56.25 && direction <= 78.75) {
    Dir = "ENE";
    } else if (direction > 78.75 && direction <= 101.25) {
    Dir = "E";
    } else if (direction > 101.25 && direction <= 123.75) {
    Dir = "ESE";
    } else if (direction > 123.75 && direction <= 146.25) {
    Dir = "SE";
    } else if (direction > 146.25 && direction <= 168.75) {
    Dir = "SSE";
    } else if (direction > 168.75 && direction <= 191.25) {
    Dir = "S";
    } else if (direction > 191.25 && direction <= 213.75) {
    Dir = "SSW";
    } else if (direction > 213.75 && direction <= 236.25) {
    Dir = "SW";
    } else if (direction > 236.25 && direction <= 258.75) {
    Dir = "WSW";
    } else if (direction > 258.75 && direction <= 281.25) {
    Dir = "W";
    } else if (direction > 281.25 && direction <= 303.75) {
    Dir = "WNW";
    } else if (direction > 303.75 && direction <= 326.25) {
    Dir = "NW";
    } else if (direction > 326.25 && direction <= 348.75) {
    Dir = "NNW";
```

Comment: Please specify what you actually want giving more details.

Comment: That code is valid C++ already.

Comment: for above code snippet ,i want compact coding means 2-3 lines of code.

Comment: @Prit You should've put that in the question. Anyway, I edited your question so it's clear now about what you were asking.

Answer (score 3):

One way to write that code would be to use an array to hold all the string values, and use some magic to transform `direction` to an index of that array:

```
const std::string Directions[16] =
{
    "N", "NNE", "NE", "ENE", "E", "ESE", "SE", "SSE",
    "S", "SSW", "SW", "WSW", "W", "WNW", "NW", "NNW"
}

// And now the magic to pick the appropriate element from the array
direction += 11.25;
if (direction >= 360.0)
    direction -= 360.0;
direction /= 22.5;
Dir = Directions[static_cast<int>(direction)];
```